Как перевести float и double в обычную дробь?
Как перевести например 3.5 в 7/2. Чтобы и числитель и знаменатель были int-ами.

Неужели никаких своих идей нет? Между прочим, в общем случае это не всегда просто с т.з. машинной арифметики

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1SNTxt38ls

было несколько попыток(неудачных)

Нужно показать свои попытки.

Поскольку не всегда такое можно из-за представления чисел с плавающей точкой, по-хорошему, через цепные дроби. Поскольку у них в определенном смысле самое точное представление.

@MBo, это всегда просто (вещественное число - дробь со степенью двойки в знаменателе). Но результат может не порадовать пользователя. :)

@Harry, я почти сделал. На .3 и 1/3 работает, а вот на 200.1 - нет. И ещё магическая константа...

Возможно, автор такой с круглыми глазами - дяденьки, а вы с кем это сейчас разговаривали... Мы от него пояснений не дождались, а не исключено, что требовалось по минимуму - три целых пять десятых равно 35/10, сократить на НОД, получить 7/2

@MBo Тот случай, когда проходной вопрос — и вдруг не закрывается, а обрастает теорией и ответами :) Люблю такие вопросы...

Спасибо за вопрос! Было о чём подумать, поговорить.

Суть вопроса — как перевести 3.5 в 3.5. То есть достать из двоичного представления назад десятичное.

Практичным решением было бы при вводе числа не читать его в double, а считать как строку и получить сразу десятичную дробь.

Оказывается, это уже обсуждалось больше 6 лет назад :)

@Harry, но тут ответы интереснее. И там автор спросил про десятичную дробь, а тут - про float и double. Надо знать, как спрашивать)))

..............XD

Я так балуюсь, над людьми угараю что думают что я серьёзно)))

Сперва я решу задачу просто, затем сложнее и правильнее.
Простое решение
x = 0.3 в формате float будет сохранено как x = 1.001100110011001100110102×2-2. Левый множитель - мантисса. Она записана как двоичная дробь. Правый множитель - экспонента в виде степени двойки. Запишем x как дробь: x = x/1. Теперь числитель и знаменатель этой дроби домножим на такой целый коэффициент, что числитель станет целым:
x/1 = 1.001100110011001100110102×2-2/1 = 0.01001100110011001100110102/1 =
= (225×0.01001100110011001100110102)/(225×1) = 1001100110011001100110102/225
Последнее выражение - обыкновенная дробь 10066330/33554432, что упрощается до 5033165/16777216.
Хотелось получить 3/10, но это число нельзя сохранить в формате float точно. При записи оно чуть-чуть меняется и получается 5033165/16777216.
NB Программа использует вещественный тип для представления числителя и знаменателя дроби. Тем не менее все промежуточные значения целые и арифметика точная.
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
std::pair<T, T> ratio(T x) {
    int e = std::max(
        std::numeric_limits<T>::digits - static_cast<int>(std::logb(x)) - 1,
        0
    );
    auto n = std::ldexp(x, e);
    for (; e > 0 && std::fmod(n, T(2)) == 0; --e, n /= 2) {
    }
    auto d = std::ldexp(T(1), e);
    return {n, d};
}

int main() {
    double x;
    std::cin >> x;
    auto r = ratio(x);
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0);
    std::cout << r.first << '/' << r.second << '\n';
}

Цепные дроби
Предыдущее решение точное. В том смысле, что оно печатает дробь, которая точно равна вещественному числу в памяти компьютера. Но, как ни странно, есть решение лучше точного.
Есть много пар целых чисел, которые будучи поделены, дадут нужное нам число x в вещественном формате. Например, x = 0.3 может быть получено и как 5033165/16777216 и как 2516581/8388603 и как 3/10. В реальной арифметике это разные числа. В машинной арифметике они равны.
Переформулируем задачу: требуется отыскать такую пару натуральных чисел, которые при делении в машинной арифметике дадут x. Инструмент для поиска - цепные дроби.
Чтобы построить цепную дробь для машинного представления x, выразим x в виде точной дроби. Например 0.3 хранится как 5033165/16777216.
Делим числитель на знаменатель с остатком и переворачиваем дробь в правой части:
5033165/16777216 = 0 + 5033165/16777216 = 0 + (16777216/5033165)-1.
Повторим для новой дроби:
16777216/5033165 = 3 + 1677721/5033165 = 3 + (5033165/1677721)-1
И ещё два раза:
5033165/1677721 = 3 + 2/1677721 = 3 + (1677721/2)-1
1677721/2 = 838860 + 1/2 = 838860 + (2/1)-1
Останавливаемся, в последнем выражении в знаменателе единица. В нотации цепных дробей
5033165/16777216 = [0; 3, 3, 838860, 2] = 0 + (3 + (3 + (838860 + 2-1)-1)-1)-1.
Будем считать дроби для частичных цепных дробей:
[0;] = 0 = 0
[0; 3] = 0 + 3-1 = 1/3
[0; 3, 3] = 0 + (3 + 3-1)-1 = 3/10
[0; 3, 3, 838860] = 0 + (3 + (3 + 838860-1)-1)-1 = 2516581/8388603
[0; 3, 3, 838860, 2] = 0 + (3 + (3 + (838860 + 2-1)-1)-1)-1 = 5033165/16777216
Каждый раз когда получена дробь в виде пары целых чисел, эти числа переводятся в вещественный формат и выполняется машинное деление. Если результат деления совпадает с исходным x в машинном представлении, задача решена.
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
std::pair<T, T> bin_ratio(T x) {
    int e = std::max(
        std::numeric_limits<T>::digits - static_cast<int>(std::logb(x)) - 1,
        0
    );
    auto n = std::ldexp(x, e);
    for (; e > 0 && std::fmod(n, T(2)) == 0; --e, n /= 2) {
    }
    auto d = std::ldexp(T(1), e);
    return {n, d};
}

template<typename T>
void cf(T n, T d, std::vector<T> &a) {
    while (d != 0) {
        a.push_back(std::floor(n / d));
        auto tmp = d;
        d = std::fmod(n, d);
        n = tmp;
    }
}

template<typename T>
std::pair<T, T> ratio(T x) {
    auto r = bin_ratio(x);
    std::vector<T> a;
    cf(r.first, r.second, a);

    auto m = a.size();
    for (unsigned i = 1; i <= m; ++i) {
        T n = 1;
        T d = 0;
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
            auto tmp = n;
            n = a[j] * n + d;
            d = tmp;
        }
        if (n / d == x) {
            return {n, d};
        }
    }
    return r;
}

int main() {
    double x;
    std::cin >> x;
    auto r = ratio(x);
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0);
    std::cout << r.first << '/' << r.second << '\n';
}


$ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion fraction.cpp

$ echo 0.3 | ./a.out
3/10

$ echo 3.5 | ./a.out
7/2

$ echo 200.1 | ./a.out
2001/10

$ echo 0.00000000001 | ./a.out
1/100000000000


P.S. Следующий раз когда вам кто-то скажет что вещественные числа нельзя сравнивать с помощью ==, покажите им эту программу. Она работает потому что так делать можно, когда знаешь что делаешь.

Правильный, но немного неожиданный результат: https://godbolt.org/z/MxT1j5r63

Как ни странно, обыкновенный std::cout справляется с «восстановлением» исходной десятичной дроби. Я набросал ссылок в комментариях к другому ответу, и под этим оказывается далеко не тривиальная теория.

@VladD, он справляется потому что выводит числа с шестью знаками после запятой. Это компромисс хорошо подходящий в большинстве случаев. Тот же компромисс можно устроить для обычных дробей. Я собираюсь дополнить ответ как раз этим решением.

А вот C# справляется лучше: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUHuAewgCMAbAUwG0BdAAiggFsBnOgXjqoAYA6TGHT6Z0g4egDMY/pIAsAVgBsAdgAcAThoBuPADNCYCgEMAxgAs6ACgBuRsHTh0AllAbMWASjx0fdVJnVLOA8tIA

@VladD, держите "теорию заговора". Я думаю что шесть знаков выбрано потому это близко к максимальной точности float. Когда создавали C вычисления на float были рациональным выбором (компьютеры не имели железной реализации вещественной арифметики, а программная реализация float значительно быстрее double). Почему для double не сделали больше - не знаю. Когда создавали С# никто в здравом уме не стал бы использовать float - он устарел и его точность устарела. В C# лучше выбраны форматы по умолчанию для печати вещественных. Кто бы сомневался. Прошло тридцать лет.

Я как человек, следивший за развитием C#, могу рассказать другую историю. Сначала там был простой и прагматичный алгоритм: округляем до N десятичных знаков, и дело с концом. Но затем появились багрепорты о том, что выводимое значение не round-trippable (как это по-русски?), и им пришлось переделать правильно.

Добавил до 18 знаков: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUHuAewgCMAbAUwG0BdAAiggFsBnOgXjqoAYA6TGHT6Z0g4egDMY/pIAsAVgBsAdgAcAThESFK1dK061muUqM0A3HgBmhMBQCGAYwAWdABQA3e2Dpw6ASygGZhYASjw6SLpUTHU3OFDLfFwYuPFtUw0DTI5OdMMsk111RKA==

@VladD, я починил "неожиданный результат".

Круто! Но вот это у меня не проходит: https://godbolt.org/z/Pbo3nf8Yb

@VladD, для 0.0001 не работает и первая программа. Потому что это 7378697629483821/73786976294838206464 и знаменатель не помещается в 64 бита. :(. Думаю.

Может, взять бесконечную точность? Или есть теоретический предел на битность числителя/знаменателя?

@VladD, я уверен, что задача решается в 64-х битах. Надо только придумать что делать большими степенями двойки в знаменателях в первой программе. Пока я добавил сообщение об ошибке. Думаю дальше.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, а в каком случае степень может быть больше? У меня точное решение без переполнений ищется. А вот к этой строчке у меня есть вопросы: T(n) / T(d) == x. Приведение n к double точно не может быть с потерей точности? В моём решении такая проблема была. UPDATE: А, нет, n/d несократима, значит не переполняется. У меня была сократимая и я вечный цикл словил на неработающем инкременте...

@Qwertiy, числитель взят из мантиссы (полная цепная дробь) или меньше (если цепная дробь обрезана), знаменатель - степень двойки для полной цепной дроби. Приведения точные. Округление возникает только при делении, но оно то нам и нужно.

@VladD, решил задачу в 64 битах. Пришлось вычисления перенести на double. Это позволяет без переполнений представлять знаменатели маленьких дробей. Вычисления точные, на целых значениях в формате с плавающей запятой. 0.00001 заработал.

Как дополнение... С цепными дробями я как-то игрался полтора года назад, было интересно. Поскольку эти дроби росли мгновенно до неимоверных значений, взял boost/multiprecision. Переписывать не хочется, просто как есть - тут, если процесс не останавливается на точном значении, до 80 таких дробей.
Вот что валяется на диске:
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp>
#include <boost/math/ccmath/floor.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::multiprecision;
using Double  = boost::multiprecision::cpp_bin_float_100;
using Integer = boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;


vector<Integer> chain(Double x)
{
    vector<Integer> a;

    Integer v = x.convert_to<Integer>();
    a.push_back(v);
    x = x - Double(v);
    for(int i = 0;x != 0 && i < 80;++i)
    {
        x = 1.0/x;
        if ((v = x.convert_to<Integer>()) == 0) break;
        a.push_back(v);
        x = x - Double(v);
    }
    return a;
}

vector<pair<Integer,Integer>> suitable(const vector<Integer>& a)
{
    vector<pair<Integer,Integer>> v;
    Integer p_1 = 1, q_1 = 0;
    Integer p0 = a[0], q0 = 1;

    v.emplace_back(p0,q0);
    for(int i = 1; i < a.size(); ++i)
    {
        Integer p = a[i]*p0 + p_1;
        Integer q = a[i]*q0 + q_1;
        v.emplace_back(p,q);
        p_1 = p0; q_1 = q0;
        p0 = p;   q0 = q;
    }
    return v;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    const char* e = "2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240766303535475945713821785251664274"
        "2746639193200305992181741359662904357290033429526059563073813232862794349076323382988075319525101901";

    const char * pi = "3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679"
        "821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659334461284756482337867831652712019091";

    Double x("200.1");

    auto z = chain(x);

    for(auto q: z) cout << q << " ";

    cout << "\n\n";

    auto y = suitable(z);

    for(auto w: y)
    {
        cout << w.first << "/" << w.second << "   ";
        Double p = w.first.convert_to<Double>();
        Double q = w.second.convert_to<Double>();
        cout << setprecision(30) << p/q << endl;
    }

}

А вот что получается для 200.1:
200/1   200
2001/10   200.1
6838576094204385719795901494472438050112018798777059508262448411603618674059298784953515417536140721/34175792574734561318320347298712833833643272357706444319152665725155515612490248800367393390985211   200.1

и 0.3:
0/1   0
1/3   0.333333333333333333333333333333
2/7   0.285714285714285714285714285714
3/10   0.3
4374501449566023848745004454235242730706338861786424872851541212819905998398751846447026354046107648/14581671498553412829150014847450809102354462872621416242838470709399686661329172821490087846820358827   0.3

Или для "пи":
3/1   3
22/7   3.14285714285714285714285714286
333/106   3.14150943396226415094339622642
355/113   3.14159292035398230088495575221
103993/33102   3.14159265301190260407226149477
104348/33215   3.14159265392142104470871594159
208341/66317   3.14159265346743670552045478535
312689/99532   3.14159265361893662339750030141
833719/265381   3.14159265358107777120441930658

Вот о точности из Википедии:

Подходящая дробь
pn/qn является наилучшим приближением исходного числа среди всех дробей, знаменатель которых не превосходит qn.

Так что, наверное, надо просто задаваться точностью представления, и обрывать ее где надо...

Кажется, можно прекращать вычисления когда результат деления становится равен заданному числу?

Он таковым в общем случае не станет. Какая дробь для иррационального числа? :)

Так комп ведь не умеет иррациональные хранить. 53 бита - и всё. Любое число из double представимо как x/2**54, где x - целое. Значит должно в какой-то момент совпасть?

@Qwertiy А, в этом смысле... я математически :) А так — вон оно решение, выше, где знаменатель всегда степень двойки... Но лучшее ли это решение?

@Harry, я доработал решение со "знаменатель всегда степень двойки". Оказалось даже лучше чем я ожидал, исходная дробь восстанавливается всегда.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Оказалось даже лучше чем я ожидал — бывает и так :)

@Harry, википедия в твоём ответе утверждает, что каждая дробь является наилучшим приближением среди всех с не большим знаменателем. Значит как только мы получим дробь, которая в double даёт в точности заданное число, мы нашли ответ с минимальным таким знаменателем. Не последнюю, где знаменатель - степень двойки, а ту, что с наименьшим знаменателем. Я ж примерно так же ищу в своём ответе. Кстати, надо подебажить, что там с 200.1 - подозреваю, что я где-то баг посадил...

@Qwertiy Ну вроде так. Что-то на ночь глядя плохо думается :)

Учитывая то, как в компьютере представляются вещественные числа, это делается умножением на 2 до тех пор, пока не получится целое число. Это всегда можно сделать без потери точности, а си и си++ даже не попытаются округлить значение при выводе (как это сделают другие языки).
Но есть нюанс. Компьютер не хранит десятичное число точно, поэтому может оказаться так, что то число, которое хранит компьютер, - это не то число, которое мы хотим увидеть. Надо ещё как-то "сократить" дробь, но под "сокращением" тут понимается округление до более красивого результата с несильной потерей точности. Как это сделать - надо ещё подумать.


function toFraction(x) {
  var den = 1

  while (x % 1) {
    x *= 2
    den *= 2
  }
  
  return x + "/" + den
}

for (var x of [200, 1, 0, 3.5, 124.375, .5, .75, .3, 1/3]) {
  console.log(x, toFraction(x))
}
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }



Для получения более красивой дроби можно сделать как-то так (насколько я вижу, работает, но не уверен в константе .125). Вместо BigInt можно использовать int64 (просто в js его нет).
UPDATE: Не всегда работает: 200.1 не может красиво вывести.


function gcd(x, y) {
  if (!x) return y ? y : 1
  if (!y) return x
  
  while (1) {
    if (!(x %= y)) return y
    if (!(y %= x)) return x
  }
}

function toFraction(x) {
  var den = 1, d = .5

  while (x + d !== x) {
    d /= 2
  }
  
  while (x % 1) {
    x *= 2
    den *= 2
  }

  var bestnom = x, bestden = den
  
  if (d * den > .125) {
    var x8 = BigInt(x)*8n, den8 = BigInt(den)*8n

    for (var y = x8 - 7n; y < x8 + 8n; ++y) {
      for (var z = den8 - 7n; z < den8 + 8n; ++z) {
        var g = gcd(y, z)

        if (bestden > z/g) {
          bestnom = y/g
          bestden = z/g
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  return {
    exact: x + "/" + den,
    optimal: bestnom + "/" + bestden,
  }
}

for (var x of [200, 1, 0, 3.5, 124.375, .5, .75, .3, 1/3, 200.1]) {
  var { exact, optimal } = toFraction(x)
  console.log(x, "=", exact, "~", optimal)
}
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }




По идее, нужно взять то, как двоичное число переводится в десятичную дробь (то есть, сделать то же, что делается при выводе числа на консоль), и дальше работать не с двоичной, а с десятичной дробью. Иначе будут получаться крокодилы.

.NET, например, делает это так: https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Number.Formatting.cs,592

А вот теория, на которую они ссылаются: https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/florian-loitsch/printf.pdf

@VladD, можно и без алгоритмов: sprintf %.8f, sscanf и сокращаем.

Ну так алгоритм будет запрятан в sprintf. Ну и sscanf не катит, вы снова получите исходное число, нужно руками прочитать десятичную дробь.

@VladD, ну если алгоритм уже в стандартной либе идёт, зачем его реализовывать самому?) Я вот только вчера из соседнего ответа узнал, что есть std::gcd))) А через sscanf читать не double, а два int64: %llu.%llu ;)

@Qwertiy, %llu.%llu исказит дробную часть для 1.01, например. Надо аккуратнее, через строку.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, да, надо хитрее, но через %llu.%n%llu%n я могу без строк: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1591523/178988.
